# Scheduled build job on azure devops stopped scheduling new builds

Tags: azure-devops

Had a scheduled job running every 30 minutes of Azure devops, it was running fine, last scheduled build I saw was on 2019-10-02·14:00, and since then there were no changes made to azure devops or even to the repository for which the pipeline builds.

Devops is not triggering any new builds, not sure about the issue and where should I look for issues.

Tried a manual run, thinking that it could invoke the sleeping process somewhere, but it did not help

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master

schedules:
- cron: "*/30 * * * *"
  displayName: Daily half-hourly build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: true

....
....
```

Answer (score 2):

For your issue ,there could be two reasons why the schedule trigger stopped scheduling new builds.

**The first one : Set the schedule trigger  in UI**

Scheduled triggers defined using the pipeline settings UI take precedence over YAML scheduled triggers.

If your YAML pipeline has both YAML scheduled triggers and UI defined scheduled triggers, only the UI defined scheduled triggers are run. To run the YAML defined scheduled triggers in your YAML pipeline, you must remove the scheduled triggers defined in the pipeline setting UI.

**The second one: Each cron schedule has a limit**

Each cron schedule has a maximum of **100** pipeline runs per week.From your description: running every 30 minutes, it should exceed the limit of 100 pipelines per week. If you need more, you can split your cron schedule into multiple cron schedules that each result in 100 or less pipeline runs per week.

You can check these two points to see if this is the cause of the issue.For details please refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers).

Comment: Thats what it looks like the 100 runs per week limit.Thanks for pointing this out, but ADO seems to have every different kind of limits, it would be great idea to showcase on failing/non-working pipelines why is the issue.

Comment: Hi,@SushilKumar  " it would be great idea to showcase on failing/non-working pipelines why is the issue"<< For this request,I have submitted a new feature request on our dc form . You can comment and vote [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/767884/showcase-on-failingnon-working-pipelines-why-is-th.html) to increase the priority of this user voice.If this answer is helpful to you ,you could accept it as the answer,so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.:)